# storm with remote hbase cluster

Tags: hbase, apache-storm

I have just started working on storm. One of my use case involves reading and writing data to/from a remote hbase table. I was wondering if it is possible to connect to a remote hbase cluster from local storm topology. If yes, how so?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

It is no different than connecting remotely from a stand-alone java application.  You may have to take care to set the parallelism hint - too high and you get too many connections and too low and you get a bottleneck - but that's really no different than connecting to any other kind of server from within storm.